# get dynamic value from input in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i have table in vue component and one of the column have input also tr tag in v-for.
how can i get all table value and submit in one time?
i mean fill all inputs and save method run one time for all of them

```html
<table >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>Costumer Name</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        <th>Total Paid</th>
        <th>Total Refund</th>
        <th>Actual Paid</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>New Pay</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr v-for="(passenger , index) in passengers">
        <td >{{ index+1 }}</td>
        <td >{{ passenger.name_ar }}</td>
        <td >{{ passenger.payment }}</td>
        <td >{{ passenger.payments+' KD' }}</td>
        <td >{{ passenger.returned+' KD' }}</td>
        <td >{{ passenger.payment.paid }}</td>
        <td >{{ passenger.payment.total_amount }}</td>
        <td >
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" :ref="passenger.id">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>


    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on, can you show us how far you got?  You already have all the passenger data.  So just add a v-model to the input and you have everything. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: @Trevor i have several inputs (all tr tags have input) and all of my inputs have one v-model whit same name and that is wrong

Comment: v-model allows you to set an object key.  v-model="passenger.input[index]" like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with v-model as suggested by others.

```
//****** Add v-model to your input**********
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="thispassenger" :ref="passenger.id">
```

In your Template have a button that will handle the submit method:

```
<button type="submit" @click="addPassaenger">Add Passenger</butoon>
```

Now you have to define thispassenger data object

```
export default {
  data() {
     return {  thispassenger : {} }
  },
// ****** method to handle the submit
methods: {
    addPassaenger() {
       //put your submit logic here
       // example axios.post('url', this.thispaasenger);
    }
 }
}
```

> Remember that v-model directive creates two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements. You can't use use it on any other elements.

If you want to learn more about v-model, please o to this link.[Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a v-model and point the current passenger that you want to submit to that v-model.

```
export default {
  data() {
  return {
    passengerModal : {}
```

Then, there will be a submit button on each passenger correct? On your submit button you can use

```
<button @click="passengerModal = passenger; submitThisPassenger()>Current passenger</button>
```

Comment: actually there is one button for all passengers and i must submit all of them with one submit button

Comment: Then its more of a backend work, just pass all the passengers as the payload.

Comment: i do it, at first create array and pushed with passengers id and with for get each input value clearly thank you @Syazany